# Can dwarves ride riding dogs?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, mount, dwarf

I am making a druid and I'm trying to decide between having a riding dog and a wolf as an animal companion. Can dwarves ride riding dogs? That could be the deciding factor.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**No.** Dwarves and riding dogs are the same size, therefore are not compatible.

According to [Rules of the Game](https://web.archive.org/web/20180430140152/http://archive.wizards.com:80/default.asp?x=dnd/rg/20050125a):

> A mount must be at least one size category bigger than the rider.

This is also on page 204 of the Dungeon Master's Guide:

> At least one size category larger than the character. Also, a flying mount can carry no more than a light load aloft.

---

[Riding Dogs][8] are [Size/Type][9]: [Medium][10]/[Animal][11]

[Dwarves](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/monsters/dwarf.htm) are Size/Type: Medium/[Humanoid](https://www.d20srd.org/srd/typesSubtypes.htm#humanoidType) (Dwarf)

Comment: I'm pretty sure Share Spells doesn't work like that, for this instance; *enlarge person* doesn't have "a target of 'You'" and the other use of Share Spells would require the druid to also gain a size category--so it wouldn't make the dog any more ridable for the dwarf. (Unless the dwarf in question *isn't* the druid whose animal companion the dog is, but I'm not reading the question that way.) The first bit of the answer is spot on, though!

Comment: I just asked [this question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/q/68168/4398) to see if there's precedent for the druid being able to dismiss *enlarge person* from himself while retaining it on the dog. (But Share Spell may introduce complications to the rule which the basic "multi-target dismissal" scenario doesn't cover.)

Comment: @BESW Be I a DM, I'd readily allow such use of enlarge person. Worth a question on it's own may be?

Comment: Man that's dissapointing. Imagine just seeing a dwarf riding towards you on a dog....I'd be scared oh well wolf it is

Comment: @Jayjay Wolves are medium size as well.

Comment: @Ruut Not going to ride the wolf. That'd be mean. No just a wolf is more badass to have as a partner

Answer (score -3):

Medium load capacity for a riding dog is 100–200 lbs., and over 200 is a heavy load. The Player's Handbook says dwarves are slightly lighter than humans which range between 125-250. Think Gimli from the Lord of the Rings on a St. Bernard. Doubtful he could carry you very fast or very far.

Comment: As noted in Ruut's answer, it doesn't matter what the carrying capacity is as a dwarf and a riding dog are the same size category.