# Can I dismiss a spell one target at a time?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, spells

If I cast a multiple-target spell with the (D) quality on my friends, can I [dismiss](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicOverview/spellDescriptions.htm#dismissible) the effect from one target while keeping it active on all the others?

For example: I cast [*hide from undead*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/hideFromUndead.htm) on myself and all my friends, then decide I want to have a chat with a vampire without exposing my friends. Can I dismiss the spell from myself but still have my friends be affected? Does the answer change if I want to dismiss it from my friend the bard while keeping myself affected?

Comment: I asked a follow-up question based on this: http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/68173/when-are-you-in-range-of-a-spells-effects

Comment: @Erik: That follow-up question might actually provide an argument that, RAW, a spell can be dismissed piecemeal - if you are only 'in range' of one of the targets, perhaps only that effect can be dismissed while the others persist. Further research needed, great questions both.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Dismissability is a duration note on the whole spell, not on parts of the spell. Dismissing a spell has the same effect as the spell's duration ending — because that's exactly what it is, but triggered voluntarily.

To be able to selectively terminate the effects of a spell affecting multiple targets would require the spell itself to offer that ability in its description.

Comment: Would a targeted [*dispel magic*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/spells/dispelMagic.htm) on yourself (or the bard) work?

Comment: @Zano If you have a related but new question, you can use the [Ask Question](http://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/ask) button to post it, and include a link to this question if it's useful for context. We're not equipped to properly answer questions that appear in the comments.

Comment: Fair enough, after all the OP didn't ask how achieve the effect, only if *dismiss* would work to that end.

Comment: @Zano Ah, I see where you're coming from. Yeah, I understood this as a rules clarification question rather than a "how to achieve this" question.

Answer (score 3):

## No

When you dismiss a spell, you dismiss the whole spell. Not just parts of it. Theoretically speaking, the target of your "dismissal" is the *spell*, not the effect of the spell on a target.